Array of function pointer in Fortran
As of now I am defining a new type and having a procedure added to it pointing to a function.
type    ::  species
    character(len=50)                   ::  species_name                    ! Species Name
    integer                             ::  species_number                  ! Species Number
    procedure(sub_crosssection), pointer, pass(self)      ::    calculate_cross_section     ! Collision Reaction        

end type


What I want is an array of function pointers, I tried
    procedure(sub_crosssection), pointer, pass(self)      ::    calculate_cross_section_ar(10)      ! Collision Reaction        


and
    procedure(sub_crosssection), allocatable, pointer, pass(self)     ::    calculate_cross_section_ar(:)       ! Collision Reaction        


However I am not able to define any of this. I wanted to know even something like this is even possible in Fortran?
TLDR: I want an array of function pointers in type data structure. Is this possible?

Arrays of pointers must use wrappers in Fortran, see the links. Your code certainly is not Fortran 90 but at least 2003.
